# UIDatePicker in UITableViewCell not displayed correctly and crashes

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I try to add UIDatePicker to UITableViewCell when user selects row. I added it programmatically to the cell and toggle its visibility on cell selection.
It works fine both on device and on simulator. but when I disconnect device or press stop in Xcode and relaunch app in simulator - UIDatePicker is cropped (partially visible) and crashes app if tapping on it.

[image]

I tried to do it in tableview controller as

```
    var groomingDatePicker: UIDatePicker = {
        let picker = UIDatePicker()
        picker.datePickerMode = .date
        return picker
    }()
```

in cellForRow...

```
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = some text
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
            
    cell.contentView.addSubview(groomingDatePicker)
    groomingDatePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    groomingDatePicker.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.rightAnchor, constant: -75).isActive = true
    groomingDatePicker.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    groomingDatePicker.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    groomingDatePicker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    if petDefaults.bool(forKey: somekey) == true 
        {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
        groomingDatePicker.isHidden = false
        } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
        groomingDatePicker.isHidden = true
        }
    return cell
```

I also tried making custom TableViewCell, result is the same

Comment: share the code that you use to create the cell.  Don't add everything, but show everything that is relevant

Comment: added some code

Comment: I think your problem is that your continually re-using a single instance of groomingDatePicker.  You could create it each time in the cellForRowAt - but you need to remember that each time the row is recreated, you will have to set the date to the selected value.  Because the cells are recycled, you can't assume that the values you enter will still be there if you scroll off the page and back again.  The table cells DO NOT contain your data - they only display it.  If you have multiple dates, you will need an array of dates somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you need is an array of reminders, you will need to have a simple data model to hold the data, because your tableView is not the data store, it's just a display of the data.  The cells are re-used, so you cannot expect to keep the value as you scroll.  Every time you display a cell, you have to treat it as a brand new display, which means you have to hold the dates in an array.

let's assume you have a simple reminder structure like this

```
struct ReminderDetails
{
    var description : String = ""
    var date        : Date   = Date() 
}
```

and you have a class variable declared like this

```
var reminders : [ReminderDetails] = []
// create some dummy data
reminders.append(ReminderDetails(description: "first thing to do", date: Date()))
reminders.append(ReminderDetails(description: "second thing to do", date: Date()))
reminders.append(ReminderDetails(description: "another thing to do", date: Date()))
```

and then when you create your cell, make sure to set the reminder date each time

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = reminders[indexPath.row].description
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    let groomingDatePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    groomingDatePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    groomingDatePicker.date = reminders[indexPath.row].date
    
    groomingDatePicker.tag = indexPath.row

    // update the stored value whenever the value is changed
    groomingDatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.datePickerValueChanged), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    
    
    cell.contentView.addSubview(groomingDatePicker)
    groomingDatePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    groomingDatePicker.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    groomingDatePicker.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    groomingDatePicker.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    groomingDatePicker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.heightAnchor).isActive = true
 
    if petDefaults.bool(forKey: somekey) == true
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
        groomingDatePicker.isHidden = false
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
        groomingDatePicker.isHidden = true
    }
    return cell
}
```

You need to take some action when the date is updated in the picker, and that's what the

```
groomingDatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.datePickerValueChanged), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
```

line is for - when the date changes, the function `datePickerValueChanged` is called, passing in the sender so that you can access the `sender.tag` which lets you know the row, and therefore which control has been updated.

```
// date changed event
@objc func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker)
{
    // update the reminder date for the right entry, based on the sender tag
    reminders[sender.tag].date = sender.date
}
```

This just updates the class array - if you're storing this in a database, you will have to update it there - either every time something is changed, or as a block at the end.

Comment: Thank You!! It is one of the best answers I ever got. It works fine, but only on device or simulator, connected to Xcode in debug mode. When I disconnect my device or stop simulator (press stop button in Xcode) and relaunch app (tap its icon on simulator screen) the problem is still the same - UIDatePicker is cropped and crashes app if tapped

Comment: @IvanVilchavskyi what height are your tableView rows?

Comment: tableViewRows are of defaults height. UIDatePicker is cropper horizontally as on my screenshot

Comment: no matter what I do to change heights, or remove constraints, I keep seeing error messages generated when I select the DatePicker, and I can't see how to clear them.

Comment: can you recommend alternative UI for creating notifications at certain dates?